appwrite is not giving user's profile image in response for oAuth
I'm using appwrite for google OAuth, but when I access user by
const user = await account.get();

then it gives only this object..
{
    "$id": "...",
    "$createdAt": "...",
    "$updatedAt": "...",
    "name": "...",
    "registration": "...",
    "status": true,
    "labels": [],
    "passwordUpdate": "",
    "email": "...",
    "phone": "",
    "emailVerification": true,
    "phoneVerification": false,
    "mfa": false,
    "prefs": {},
    "targets": [
        {
            "$id": "...",
            "$createdAt": "...",
            "$updatedAt": "...",
            "name": "",
            "userId": "...",
            "providerId": null,
            "providerType": "email",
            "identifier": "..."
        }
    ],
    "accessedAt": "..."
}

i want user's profile image also
enter image description here
I've selected all the options in auth menu but it still not giving user's profile image in response.
